# Htaccess problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just created a htaccess file and entered the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/profile/([0-9]+)\.html /profile.php?id=$1
```

This is giving me a

> 500 Internal Server Error

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: I don't really know much about this, what would I be looking for?

Comment: Anything that happened around the time you tried your request and got a 500 response. Log messages often contain at least partially readable messages in English that may give hints as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Ahhh I see, the error is caused by me adding that code but to find the server logs, I am having problems. Are they usually in the root directory??

Comment: Depends on the OS/distribution. On the ones I'm most familiar with they usually end up somewhere in /var/log.

Comment: I've found where the logs are, and found the log I think is relevant...no idea what any of it means though. Does the code for the .htaccess file look reasonable (what I originally posted)???

Answer (score 1):

use this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)\.html$ /profile.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: it means: Appends any query string created in the rewrite target to any query string that was in the original request URL.